# How to fetch data from a different firebase project?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Scenario** I have created two projects in firebase using command line tools. The first site(say A) is a web-app that uses hosting, firestore, cloud functions and auth. The second site(say B) is sort of admin-portal which should be able to show all the data in site-A. Site-B uses different Auth than site-A.

**Note** More sites like site-A will be created in future and site-B will remain the admin-portal of all of them.

**Question** How to bring the data from one project in firebase to some other project?

**PS** I know that SO doesn't allow this but if there is a better way of doing this, I would be very happy to know.

Comment: Why must you use 2 separate projects?

Comment: I do not have any proper reason for that. I once thought that if I use separate projects then the document reads and writes will be spread across projects and I will get more free quota but I have never checked this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to initialize Firebase multiple times, once for each project.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#initialize_multiple_apps):

```
// Initialize the default app
firebase.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);

// Initialize another app with a different config
var otherApp = firebase.initializeApp(otherAppConfig, "other");

console.log(firebase.app().name);  // "[DEFAULT]"
console.log(otherApp.name);        // "other"

// Use the shorthand notation to retrieve the default app's services
var defaultStorage = firebase.storage();
var defaultDatabase = firebase.database();

// Use the otherApp variable to retrieve the other app's services
var otherStorage = otherApp.storage();
var otherDatabase = otherApp.database();
```